# Open subset of quadric hypersurface is simply connected

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

Let $Q$ and $Q'$ be quadric hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^7$ such that $Q$ is smooth. In a calculation I'm doing (not worth mentioning) I have a strong reason to believe

> $X=Q\setminus Q'$ is simply connected.

How can one prove this? What is a general result (e.g. replace $Q$ by a rational variety)? Thank you.

Comment: This follows from Lefschetz hyperplane theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_hyperplane_theorem

Comment: Can you explain a little bit, please? I mean, my $X$ is not closed, unlike the $Y$ in Lefschetz. Thank you.

Comment: you're right, I misread the OP. Let's see what others have to say :)

Comment: The title is misleading, since you are not asking about the intersection.

Comment: I do not understand how $X$ can be non-smooth if $Q$ is, since it is just an open set in $Q$. Secondly, $X$ is not simply connected in general. By Lefschetz, it follows that Picard group of $X$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then, it is well known that $X$ has two to one cover, showing that it is not simply connected.

Comment: I'm sorry I have edited the question. Where can I read about the 2 to 1 cover result, please?

Comment: What is X?   $\,\,$

Comment: If $X$ is any variety and $L$ a torsion line bundle with, say order $m$, then the spectrum of the algebra $\mathcal{O}_X\oplus L\oplus\oplus L^2\oplus\cdots \oplus L^{m-1}$ gives a variety and the map to $X$ is an $m$ to one cover.

Comment: Does this show in general that if a variety $X$ (maybe quasi-projective) has Picard group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ then it is not simply connected? Is it still true if we replace $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, simply connected varieties (in characteristic zero) have Picard group torsion free.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother again. What if the two to one cover has a branch locus. Does this affect anything?

Comment: If you create a cover using a torsion line bundle as I have described earlier, it is etale.

Comment: @Mohan This is also true for, say, proper geometrically integral varieties over $k$ of characteristic $p$, at least torsion that is not a power of $p$. As I know you know (this is for the benefit of the OP) this is just Kummer theory. To OP, this is slightly less magical (although incredibly beautiful) if one just thinks about in terms of the Kummer sequence $1\to \mu_n\to \mathbf{G}_m\to\mathbf{G}_m\to 1$. Taking the long exact sequence in (etale) cohomology gives $1\to R^\times/(R^\times)^n\to \text{Hom}_{\text{cont.}}(\pi_1(X),\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\to \text{Pic}(X)[n]\to 1$ where

Comment: $R=\mathcal{O}_X(X)$. Note that, really, I cheated since what should be in the center of the exact sequence on cohomology is $H^1(X,\mu_n)$, but I'm assuming that we're working over an algebraically closed field of chracteristic coprime to $n$ so that $\mu_n\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as etale sheaves and then using the fact that $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is the Hom-group I wrote down above. Mohan then just described explicitly how to write down all principal $\mu_n$-bundles as the relative spectrum of that quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra. It's worth noting that where this

Comment: $R^\times/(R^\times)^n$ is coming into play in Mohan's answer is that really to make the module he wrote down an algebra one uses tensor product, but one needs to fix an isomorphism $L^{\otimes n}\xrightarrow{\approx}\mathcal{O}_X$ to cycle round the tensors. Such isomorphisms differ by $n^\text{th}$-powers in the global sections, and thus the $R^\times/(R^\times)^n$ term.